# Why MySQL 5.5 needs Postfix

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, postfix

I can't figure out why MySQL 5.5 installs also Postfix. I'm not using Postfix at all and I would like uninstall it, or better just install MySQL 5.5 without Postfix.

Edit:
I'm using Dotdeb packages on a Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: On which distribution ?

Comment: Oh sorry, you right. I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 32bit with Dotdeb packages.

Answer (score 1):

Is any MTA installed in your system?

Some software needs working MTA as dependency for messaging. Base system needs it too. Sure, we can remove MTA completely, but even `cron` want to send commands output by email to the corresponding user. Seems that mysql found lack of MTA in your system and enlist it as dependency for notification purposes.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. My problem it's with MySQL 5.1 from Ubuntu repository I could install it without any MTA.

Comment: Anyway, configured MTA will not abuse your host except some rare  cases. Even if you don't plan to use your host as MX, you can use MTA as SMTP sender. So don't check it out during installation.

Comment: You right, but I'm using MSMTP instead of Postfix, but I figured out why its install Postfix. Seems to be that Postfix is a recommended package and apt-get install install recommended packages. So I just added --no-install-recommends.